# Backup software for Windows befitting my needs

Tags: windows, backup, gui

I've done countless hours of research, tried tens of programs, and have yet to find a backup program that meets my specifications:

**It must:**

- Support both file- and image-based backups.
- Save symlinks and junctions (instead of traversing them) in both image AND file backups.
- Allow me to selectively choose which files and folders to restore from both file AND image backups.
- Provide a [treeview interface with checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr1Ew.gif) through which to choose my backup targets.
- Be able to launch one or more programs of my choosing both pre- and post-backup.
- Compress backups, ideally using LZMA.
- Secure backups using AES-256 encryption and password protection.
- Output to a single file.
- Backup in-use files using Volume Shadow Copy (or a comparable technology).
- Auto-purge old backups after <x> days or <x> backups.
- Have a GUI.
- Not be written in Java.
- Be in active development. I define this as having been updated in the past year.

**It should:**

- Support what Acronis calls ["version chaining"](http://www.acronis.com/support/documentation/ATIH2012/index.html#10805.html).
- Support the mounting of backup archives.
- Support block-level/reverse delta backups.

Does such a piece of software exist?

Comment: probably not fitting all requirments (hence only a comment) but `bvckup2` ist really good

Comment: I like `bvckup2` as well, but unfortunately it does not support any versioning—it is very good at one thing and one thing only: making an _exact_ duplicate of a folder (really fast). I'm now looking for something to supplement `bvckup2` in fact, in order to fit my versioning needs. The "version chaining" concept sounds like exactly what I'd like to have.

Comment: Found this in their forums though; the developer himself: _"Alex Pankratov: [Versioning] in the plans, but I want to do it right. General idea is to adopt an open format for storing past versions, so that users won't be locked into bvckup. More specifically, I am thinking of using git, but I need to spend some time understanding how its packaging (compression) works and if it can be effectively used in the backup context (e.g. if it allows trimming older versions, etc). All in all, this is a big feature, it will take time to research and implement, but I *am* planning to add it."_

Comment: Have you considered setting your computer up with a RAID configuration instead? Also, why are "Not be written in Java." and "Have a GUI." mandatory?

Comment: The built in backup solution in Windows 7 fulfills many of these requirements. Alas it does not purge old backups so I have had to schedule a little perl script to delete old backup sets.

Comment: @Pharap RAID is not meant for backups.

Comment: Time machine is so far the best application for backup I have encountered and this answer might be helpful. You can find details on this page of our sister-site SuperUser: [Does an equivalent of Time Machine exist for Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/7423/143340)

Comment: Please tell which all backup apps you already tried.

Comment: Your question is now 6 months old and has only one answer. It may be related to the large list of requirements. Consider adding a bounty.

Comment: "not be written in Java" :D

Comment: Your list is quite comprehensive. I doubt that there is a single piece of software that does it all. Would you consider to priorise the items, so that we see what is really important to you?

Comment: I've liked [BURP](http://burp.grke.org/) a lot recently.

Comment: Adding a bounty won't help. I've been looking for similar software and I believe it has to be invented.

Comment: With such a specific feature requirement, I can only imagine that you would have to get this custom written for yourself. I don't believe you will find something as specific as this out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

[Try using EaseUS Todo Backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm), the free version. It might not be perfect but will allow you to slice up the backup into any size you want as well as compress the info. As for security, it may not have AES 256 bit but if security is that big of a problem shouldn't your hard drive already be encrypted?

Maybe try using a TC variant, there should be one at cipher-shed's web page, that would give you the security that you want hopefully.