# Free/ AUD Backup Solution

Tags: backup, data-recovery

Okay, so because this forum can be used for personal opinion, I want your opinion. 
Recently I have been using [EaseUS ToDo Backup](http://www.easeus.com/backup-software/tb-free.html) to perform the following:

```
Copy Disk1\Filepath\* to Disk2\Filepath\* as a full backup every second night at 08.00pm
Copy Disk1\Filepath\* to Disk2\Filepath\* as a differential backup at 08.30pm
Copy Disk2\* to Disk3\* every Monday and Friday at 08.00pm
```

Recently I have had an issue with my PC and has prompted me to recover some OS files on the PC. To ensure no data was lost I recovered from a backup. I am not too sure if this is a limitation of the free version, but it appears to "skip compressed files", so therefore it skips **everything in the backup.**

Thankfully I have not lost any data, so this is of no concern. I have now currently performed another backup and have removed the compression; this appears to have worked fine. (I am in the process of doing a full drive backup). Thankfully I have noticed this now as I can only imagine months down the track I'll need to restore only to have no data!

This tool, even whilst free, has the potential to cover everything I need. However, I'd much prefer to pay $30-100.00AU and have multiple PC's covered to a localised location.

Here is the scenario I am planning on configuring:

```
Copy PC1\C$\Backup\ \\Network\Path\User1
Copy PC2\C$\Backup\ \\Network\Path\User2
Copy PC3\C$\Backup\ \\Network\Path\User3
```

Now on these local PC's I want the user to be able to select what they want to backup, and then to also password protect their own items - I respect people's privacy and do not want to be able to access my families files. The requirements of the software are to complete the following:

1. Must be able to have password protection on the files to prevent access;
2. Must be able to configure a time schedule for tasks to complete;
3. Must be able to store [x] amount of backups and verify data;
4. Must be able to backup to a network path as well as local.

Please feel free to list your advise and why you believe it a valid option. I will keep looking into this.

Comment: In the end I decided to use three different tools to perform what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Cobian Backup`](http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.htm) was the solution I have used to fulfil my needs.

For configuring remote management of the other computers in my house, I can setup a home domain scenario (which also allows for remote deployment of the software). Upon initial install you are greeted with the following:

[image: Initial Installation]

The installation is very straight forward and is over quite quick. In the process the program also offers you the option to generate a script for deployment. One of the cool things with this software is that it allows you to `install`, `uninstall`, `stop` and `start` both the main server and volume shadow copy. You can also define who has access to this:

[image: Service and Volume Shadow Request]

Now as you can see in the `tools` option I am able to `decrypt`, `decompress`, `delete`, `encode` and `remote manage`; a number of key features I require.

[image: Tools Option]

Using this tool allows me to remote manage the PC's on the home LAN by installing the application. I have not played around with this feature too much but it appears I can execute remote backup policies from my PC.

[image: Remote Management]

To further help me with network backups and other computer backups, I was able to configure `E-Mail Notifications` via the program to notify me of the completion and failures. You're also able to edit the logging of the program to help monitor backup tasks.

[image: Mail Log]

Lastly I was able to configure the compression used for the backups to allow maximum efficiency on the program:

[image: Compression]

I have performed several full and incremental backups to the network path so far and have not had any issue. The only option I cannot locate is a `file validation` tool to ensure my data is not corrupted in the process. For this I may perform a simple `robocopy` of the local backup.