# Program to make automatic backups

Tags: windows, backup, archiving

I am looking for a tool or program to make automatic backups from a directory to a server, both in the same IP range.

It would be interesting if that program is capable of making differential backups and easy to use as it is for unexperienced users.
And also it would be interesting if it auto-closes and the end of work.
If it could be programmed to start working as it's opened it would be 5 stars.

Mainly it should be used under Windows 7 and Windows 10. i would prefer a free to use program, but i think 10/20$ per license/year would be interesting. I am checking FreeFileSync and it seems nice, it would be great if able to zip file in destination folder.

If someone could let me know any suggestion it would be appreciated, thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you already look at the numerous [tag:windows][tag:backup] questions on this site? I am sure that one will contain the answer which you seek. If not, you could list some of the proposed solutions and tell us why they doen't work for you, because this is such a broad question that I can't believe that it has not already been answered

Answer (score 1):

You can make backup with http://www.areca-backup.org/

it makes all you need and can put in internet.

Comment: "it makes all you need and can put in internet"? I'm sorry, I don't quite follow.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this is **Software Recommendations**, the software I'll recommend to you is Powershell. You can make [robust scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-write-and-run-scripts-in-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6) to meet you requirements above listed.

**Does it meet your requirements?**

- Does it backup a directory to a server? Yes, it does.
- Easy to use? We're going to automate it.
- Free? Yes!
- Windows 7/8/10 supported? Oh yeah!

I would recommend you [look at my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/48340/9311), rather than me regurgitate it on another question.

An example script for you to use is as follows:

```
$Source = "C:\Your\Path\Here"
$Destination = "D:\Your\WD\Passport\"
robocopy.exe $Source $Destination /E /ZB /SEC /ETA /LOG+file:my_file.txt
```

You simply make `$Source` equal the directory you wish backed up, and `Destination` the server path.

You can then schedule this to run on PC boot/shutdown, or even periodically with no user intervention required.

Comment: Does this robocopy sync or just copy? How do I sycnc 2 offline folders?

Answer (score 1):

[Z-DBackup](https://www.z-dbackup.com//backup.html) is everything you need. It can

- Backup to a server.
- differential backups and
- easy to use as it is for unexperienced users.
- auto-closes
- programmed to start working
- Windows 7 and Windows 10

I am using it with ease. Other Options can be found [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/z-dbackup/)