# Rsnapshot like tool for windows file backups

Tags: windows, backup

I use a Win10 laptop and right now take full copies of my docs folder to an external Hard Drive. This takes a long time (for about  50 GB docs) and is wasteful of storage space.

I do know of other tools (e.g. Free File Sync https://freefilesync.org/) but they seem to only solve the speed problem by not copying files that have not changed since the last backup.

But what I really want is behavior like rshapshot (on linux) where I can have a different folder for each time I took a backup but just the changed files are present in later backups. The advantage is suppose I want to view a file as of a certain date of backup this "snapshot" feature allows me to do that.

Any recommendations? Both free and paid software are fine!

[Free automatic backup tool for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/free-automatic-backup-tool-for-windows)

Comment: I see you posed this question 4 months ago. Did you find any kind of solution? I was using Linux and Timeshift (is rsnapshot behind that maybe?) and that's the sort of thing I want to emulate in W10. Of course, it's not helped by the fact that in W10 you don't have this concept of hard links, which makes it possible to implement the wonderful snapshotting of Timeshift.

Comment: @Mike. No sadly no solution so far. I am still looking.

Comment: Check this out: https://superuser.com/q/1245978/419196 ... use of WSL, which I have only glimpsed at as yet.  So if you fancy a learning curve ...!